# prove that $f$ periodic, continuous, $f(x+r)=f(x)+c$ cannot be satisfied with $r\ne 0$ and $c\ne 0$

Tags: periodic-functions

Prove that if $f$ is periodic, continuous, there are no $r\ne 0$ and $c\ne 0$ constants satisfying $f(x+r)=f(x)+c$ (for all $x$)

Let's assume that exist $r$ and $c$ satisfying $f(x+r)=f(x)+c$. Thus, by induction, $f(x+ nr)=f(x)+nc$ , where $n \in Z$.

If $r$ is a period of $f$, then $c=0$, it's okay.

If exist $n,m \in Z$: $np=mr$, where p is a period of $f$, then it is done, because $f(x+mr)=f(x)+mc$ and $f(x+m r)=f(x+np)=f(x)$, thus $c=0$.

I tried in this way, but I have stuck: let's assume that exist $r$ and $c$ satisfying $f(x+r)=f(x)+c$. Thus, by induction, $f(x+ nr)=f(x)+nc$ , where $n \in Z$. So, if $f$ would be bounded, I would be done, because $f(x)+nc$ is not bounded. But $\tan(x)$ is periodic, continuous and not bounded, it's a counter-example.

I need some hint, thanks for advance.

Comment: By $c<>0$, do you mean $c\ne 0$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yeah, I'm just learning this tex editing commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous it is bounded.

We have $f(x+nr) = f(x) + nc$, hence letting $n \to \infty$, we must have $c=0$.

Since $f$ is periodic, we can choose $r$ to be the period which gives
$f(x+nr) = f(x)$.

So the most we can conclude is that $c = 0$.

Comment: okay, but $tan(x)$ is not bounded, but continuous, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: $\tan$ is not continuous.

Comment: Let $T$ be the period. Then $[0,T]$ is compact and so $f$ is bounded on $[0,T]$ and hence on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: okay, $tan$ actually is not continuous at x=0, it's my mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Well, $\tan$ **is** continuous at $x=0$, but not at ${\pi \over 2}$, for example.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped

Comment: tan is continuous everywhere it is defined. It is not defined at $\pi/2$, so it's not a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.